# how to create and run programs on windows OS system in the background

Tags: windows

i want to know how to create and as well as  run a programs and those programs are to be run till the shut down time ,more specifically those programs should run by themselves when system is started .. plz if any one of u know, kindly let me know the procedure clearly..
  Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

One of the better option is to use Windows Services:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9(VS.80).aspx